# Rotating an analog dial toward the mouse/pointer in Windows 8 / XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I've implemented an Analog dial in Windows 8 XAML, and it almost works

However, when turning the dial it shakes like crazy. it seems to rotate almost 90 degrees clockwise and anticlockwise while being moved. I've implemented it using `PointerPressed`, `PointerReleased` and `PointerMoved`

My Code

```
private void dial_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dialPressed = true;    
}

private void dial_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dialPressed = false;
}

private void dial_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(dialPressed)
    {
        Windows.UI.Input.PointerPoint currentLocation = 
              e.GetCurrentPoint(dial); 

        Point dialCenter = 
              new Point(dial.ActualHeight / 2, dial.ActualWidth / 2);

        double radians = Math.Atan(
              (currentLocation.Position.Y - dialCenter.Y) / 
              (currentLocation.Position.X - dialCenter.X));

        RotateTransform r = new RotateTransform();
        r.Angle = radians * 180 / Math.PI;

        if (currentLocation.Position.X - dialCenter.X < 0)
        {
            r.Angle += 180;
        }

        TransformGroup t = new TransformGroup();
        t.Children.Add(r);
        dial.RenderTransform = t;

    }
}
```

Should I be binding against different events? What's making my dial shaky?

Comment: Shouldn't it be r.Angle += 360;? You are doing that so you don't have any negative angles right?

Comment: No, I don't think it should. If I change that to 360 it flips completely once I go past 90 degrees. With it set to 180 it acts as it is supposed to (apart from the shaking)

Comment: ok, if I replace e.GetCurrentPoint(myimage) with e.GetCurrentPoint(this) it's suddenly stable, but it's no longer turning about the centre correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved my problem.

The code was from a WPF example and a few things are different in windows 8! Here's what worked for me.

```
if (dialPressed)
{

  // Get the current mouse position relative to the dial
  // I was doing this relative to the dial that was turning, which is wrong. 
  // The position of the pointer relative to the dial will change as the dial turns!
  // I created a static dial behind it, the same dimensions
  Windows.UI.Input.PointerPoint currentLocation = 
                                e.GetCurrentPoint(this.dial_Static); 

  Point dialCenter = 
        new Point(this.dial.ActualHeight / 2, this.dial.ActualWidth / 2);

  // Calculate an angle
  double radians = Math.Atan((currentLocation.Position.Y - dialCenter.Y) /                           
                             (currentLocation.Position.X - dialCenter.X));

  // in order to get these figures to work, I actually had to *add* 90 degrees to it,     
  // and *subtract* 180 from it if the X coord is negative. 
  double x = (radians * 180 / Math.PI) + 90;
  if ((currentLocation.Position.X - dialCenter.X) < 0)
  {
     x = x - 180;
  }

  RotateTransform r = new RotateTransform();
  r.Angle = x;

  TransformGroup t = new TransformGroup();
  t.Children.Add(r);
  dial.RenderTransform = t;

}
```

I know this code could be written a lot neater, but I'm trying to keep it as close to the version above to show what's changed.